# Stored procedure returns NULL value to the output parameter IN VBA

Tags: vba, adodb

I have my stored procedure with an input parameter and an output parameter. I created parameters and was able to execute the job for the first time and received the output value in `vJobstatus` variable. When I triggered the stored procedure for a second time, I am getting NULL in `cmd.Parameters("@vJobStatus").Value`.

Please help me to get the value of output parameter. TestJob1 is triggered, but the output value is NULL.

```vb
Public pm As ADODB.Parameter
Public cnnStr, StrQuery, vJobName As String
Public RunStatus, vJobStatus As Integer
Global Flag_Chkbox As Integer


Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "Run_SQL_Job"
cmd.CommandTimeout = 120
Set pm = New ADODB.Parameter

Set pm = cmd.CreateParameter("@vJobName", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, "TestJob")
cmd.Parameters.Append pm
      
Set pm = cmd.CreateParameter("@vJobStatus", adInteger, adParamOutput, , vJobStatus)
cmd.Parameters.Append pm
    
cmd.Execute
vJobStatus = cmd.Parameters("@vJobStatus").Value
       
If vJobStatus <> 1 Then
    cnn.Close
    Application.Interactive = True
    Application.StatusBar = ""
    Exit Sub
Else
    cmd.Parameters("@vJobName").Value = "TestJob1"
    cmd.Execute
    vJobStatus = cmd.Parameters("@vJobStatus").Value
```

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Run_SQL_Job] 
      @vJobName VARCHAR(50)  
     ,@vJobStatus INTEGER  OUTPUT 
AS

DECLARE @vRunStatus as INT
DeclarE @vJobStats as INT

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:5';
SET @vRunStatus = (SELECT Runstatus from [dbo].[VIEW])

WHILE @vRunStatus >= 1
 BEGIN
   SET @vRunStatus = (SELECT Runstatus from [dbo].[VIEW])
 END

IF @vRunStatus = 0 
  BEGIN
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @vJobname 
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10';
  END
  
SET @vRunStatus = (SELECT Runstatus from [dbo].[VIEW])
    
WHILE @vRunStatus >= 1
 BEGIN
   SET @vRunStatus = (SELECT Runstatus from [dbo].[VIEW])
 END

SELECT @vJobStatus = run_status FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
             where instance_id = (SELECT max(instance_id) from msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory where step_name = @vJobName)
GO
```

Comment: How do you know it's not coming from the stored procedure?

Comment: There are at leat four different ways to return values from stored procedures. Please post your stored procedure code so we know how you're doing it.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, I have posted the stored procedure.

Comment: @GSerg, when I used Debug.print cmd.Parameters("@vJobStatus").Value, it is NULL

Comment: And how do you know that the NULL is not what actually came from the stored procedure?

Comment: I ran the sql statements manually when the job was running, procedure gives either  1 or 0 but not NULL.

Comment: Add `set @vJobStatus = isnull(@vJobStatus, 42)` to the end of your procedure and see if you get 42 in VBA.

Comment: Accirding to this, you appear to have all the syntax correct. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34145873/using-output-parameter-from-sql-server-stored-procedure-in-access managing SQL Agent jobs is a bit of a nightmare. I suggest you literally run this SP manually at the same time and confirm it doesn't return NULL

Comment: `vJobStatus` should be declared as a `Long` if you are using `adInteger`. `adInteger` is a 4 byte integer.